# Take photo programmatically in Android

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I am developing an Android app which make use of camera...and my app's requirement is:

I want to capture picture without disturbing the foreground applications and store this image to **png** format on device storage.

Comment: The camera can only be used by one application at a time.

Comment: http://kk-mishra.blogspot.in/ ..check this link

Comment: You need a custom camera. Check this out https://github.com/search?q=android+custom+camera&ref=cmdform

Comment: i hope this will be helps you http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/05/taking-picture-and-video-from-camera.html

Comment: sweta, I think you want to use your camera in background?? or simply you just need to capture photos from camera and save it????

Comment: @pratik I wants to upload this photo on FTP.

Comment: on FTP means on server na?

Comment: yup @pratik after taking image I want to send it on server.

Comment: I knows only that how to take picture automatically.

Comment: okay then let me send you the code to send image to server ok sweta

Comment: @pratik I know that how to upload images, I want to knows only that how to take picture automatically.

Comment: @SwetaSharma ohh ok automatically means??? without pressing any buttons , after some time of intervals you want to capture picture?

Comment: @pratik I take only one picture, but that's automatic without click shutter button.

Comment: okay, so you took it or not actually? or that thing is remaining?

Comment: @SwetaSharma actually I have one code like your requirement. But still need to understand your requirement proper.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52805/discussion-between-sweta-sharma-and-pratik)

Comment: @SwetaSharma hey have you done that or not?

Comment: @SwetaSharma hey still issue in this concept???

Comment: @pratik I found the solution.

Comment: @SwetaSharma heyyy hi

Answer (score 0):

HI Use the Following code:

Add the following code inside your button Click Event:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
            + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String new_Date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
            + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            + "-" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    Strin imageUrl = String.format(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                    + "/%s.png", "image(" + new_Date + ")");
    DealershipApplication.setVehicleImage(imageUrl);

    File photo = new File(imageUrl);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("exit", "false");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    YourActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Add this permissions in your manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />

<activity
    android:name="com.android.camera.Camera"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:taskAffinity="android.task.camera"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: what you meant in that question. What i meant and answered is not matters.

Comment: Of course it matters what you answer. Your answer doesn't fit the question. You copied basic image capture code, when the question was how to take a picture **without** a UI. Your answer doesn't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to call Intent for Camera as well as to open Gallery, after that you need to choose image and you will get callback of it in `onActivityResult()`, there you will get selected image path, using that selected image path, decode it and you will get image bitmap.